# Attaching spaces closed subset proof closedness

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, geometric-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be non empty topological spaces. Consider $X\coprod Y = (X\cup 0) \cup (Y\times 1)$. We define a topology on $X\coprod Y$ by declaring $U$ is open in $X\coprod Y$ if and only if $\iota_{1}^{-1}(U)$  is open in $X$ and $\iota_2^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Y$. Here, $\iota_1:X\rightarrow X\coprod Y$ is given by $\iota_1(x)=(x,0)$  and $\iota_2$ is defined similarly. In particular, $\iota_2(y)=(y,1)$.

Now let $A\subseteq X$ be closed. Suppose $f:A\rightarrow Y$ is continuous.  Then we may consider the adjunction space $X\cup_f Y= (X\coprod Y)/((a,0)\sim (f(a),1))$  which identifies $a$ with $f(a)$ for all $a\in A$.

We may abuse notation and write $(a,0)$ as $a$ and $(f(a),1)$ as $f(a)$.

***Problem:***

Let $X$ be space space and $A$ non empty closed subset of $X$. Let $f:A\rightarrow Y$ be continuous. Assume $C\subseteq X\coprod Y$ is such that $\iota_1^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$. Then

$q(C)$ is closed in $X\cup_f Y$ if and only if $\iota_{2}^{-1}(C)\cup f(\iota_{1}^{-1}(C)\cap A)$ is closed in $Y$.

***My attempt:*** If $q(C)$ is closed in $X\cup_f Y$ then $q^{-1}q(C)$ is closed in $X\coprod Y$ . In particular, $\iota_{2}^{-1}q^{-1}q(C)$ is closed in $Y$. As $\iota_{2}^{-1}q^{-1}q(C)= \iota_{2}^{-1}(C)\cup f(\iota_{1}^{-1}(C\cap A))$, the result then follows.

Is this proof correct? Why is the assumption $\iota_{1}^{-1}(C)$ closed important?

Note that $q$ is the canonical projection map

Comment: What is $q(C)$ in your question?

Comment: @Zhiyan image of canonical projection map

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of the "only if" is correct, now you have to prove the other direction. By going backwards on your proof, we already know that if $i_2^{-1}(C) \cup f(i_1^{-1}(C \cap A))$ is closed, then so is $i_2^{-1}q^{-1}q(C)$, we are now left to show that $i_1^{-1}q^{-1}q(C)$ is closed to conclude that $q^{-1}q(C)$ is closed in $X \sqcup Y$, which will imply that $q(C)$ is closed. Now since

$$i_1^{-1}q^{-1}q(C) = i_1^{-1}(C) \cup f^{-1}(i_2^{-1}(C) \cup f(i_1^{-1}(C \cap A)) $$

then by the hypothesis that $i_1^{-1}(C)$ is closed, that $f$ is continuous and that $i_2^{-1}(C) \cup f(i_1^{-1}(C \cap A)$ is closed, we conclude that $i_1^{-1}q^{-1}q(C)$ is closed.